# The provided statistics stream is corrupt, when running UPDATE Statistics

Tags: sql-server

When running
    UPDATE STATISTICS mytable

I'm getting following error:
The provided statistics stream is corrupt.

When our application is inserting rows to mytable we are getting the same error.

However 
DBCC CHECKDB
Doesn't give any errors.

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

We are running Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition with Advanced Services 2008 R2

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug.  You need CU11 for Server 2008 R2 SP2

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2829845

> VSTS bug #: 1790001
>
> FIX: "The provided statistics stream is corrupt" when you run the
> "UPDATE STATISTICS" statement against a table in SQL Server 2008 R2 or
> SQL Server 2012

Comment: I'll give that a try now and mark as answer if it works, any idea why this only started happening today after an update to our application which uses sql as a store, it happened on two separate servers).

Comment: Why now?  Maybe the bug is only triggered in certain circumstances.  The application update may have changed database schema.

Comment: No, I'm the application developer, it didn't change the schema or anything to do with the table that is throwing the error (e.g. mytable). However we did add a column to a totally unrelated table. Do you think that still could have triggered it. We did this via SQL Management Studio (not via the application).

Comment: @DermFrench A hundred different things could have triggered this. Stop trying to find an explicit cause; what will that get you? It's a bug, not your fault. Just patch it and move on...

Comment: I'm getting this error when I try and patch with the patch suggested by David: The version of SQL Server instance SQLEXPRESS does not match the version expected by the SQL Server update. 

The installed SQL Server product version is 10.50.1600.1, and the expected SQL Server version is 10.52.4000.0.

Comment: Ah I think I need to install SP2 to SQL first.